# url masking mod_rewrite

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, masking

I am slowly but surely learning php, and all is going well up until now.

I am looking to do a url rewrite, my DB is relatively indepth and a typical url would look like:

players.php?position=1&teamid=4&playerid=129

basically i want to return /Defender/Arsenal/Thomas-Vermaelen/ which are basically the names associated with the ID's in the database. This one page generates lots of different pages and I wanted to workout how to use the name in the URL instead of the ID number.

Im 99% sure this can be done as I have been looking in detail at the Joomla CMS system, and wondered if anyone could help shed some light on this please?

Thanks in advance

Richard :)

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you want to do? Do you want requests to "players.php?position=1&teamid=4&playerid=129" to be redirected to "Defender/Arsenal/Thomas-Vermaelen/"? Or vice-versa?

Comment: I basically want to mask the URL to be more SEO friendly, so instead of using "players.php?position=1&teamid=4&playerid=129" i want the user to see /Defender/Arsenal/Thomas-Vermaelen/

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest would be to simply map the requested URI `/Defender/Arsenal/Thomas-Vermaelen/` onto `/players.php?position=Defender&teamid=Arsenal&playerid=Thomas-Vermaelen`:

```
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/$ /players.php?position=$1&teamid=$2&playerid=$3
```

Then in you PHP script you can check whether the parameter value was numeric or alphabetic and fetch the the numeric ID in case of the latter.

Comment: thanks for this, very useful. At the moment all my calls to the database are using ID numbers, so would i need to change these to use the name instead, so I can return position=defender instead of position=2. I guess i was hoping I could still call the IDS but do something clever to return the name instead :)